# How to store class hierarchy so I can generate a tree most efficiently?

Tags: c#, javascript

```
List<myObject> objects = new List<myObject>

myObject
{
    string a;
    string b;
}
```

`a` holds the name of the `objects[i]`, and `b` holds the name of the parent of `objects[i]`.

How can I serialize this list to a file so I can later create a tree-like image?

As an example, `objects` list has four elements:

```
{a=planet, b=solarsystem}, 
{a=moon, b=planet}
{a=solarsystem, b=universe}
{a=meteor, b=solarsystem}
```

I want to serialize this so I can later, using javascript, read the file and have enough information to generate this diagram:

[image: tree]

Comment: Why aren't you considering object graph to be passed on client and traverse through your object?

Comment: Wow...that flew over my head. Let me do a quick google search into 'object graph'. EDIT: It seems object graph is used to serialize the actual hierarchy of your class objects. In my case, my class objects are storing information about class objects.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem then I could actually show you something that might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would have designed it this way:

I would have a C# class which would be later serialized to JSON and used it on JavaScript

Basically we will be defining hierarchy using objects and that's what is called object graph.

As it seems, the objects you have mentioned are of same type so we call it a `Node`.

```
public class Node {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> ChildNodes { get; set; }
}
```

And using this, create your object hierarchy:

```
private Node CreateXBonezNodes() {
    Node universeNode = new Node("Universe");
    Node solarSystemNode = new Node("Solar System");
    Node planetNode = new Node("Planet");
    Node meteorNode = new Node("Meteor");
    Node moonNode = new Node("Moon");

    //Now define the hierarchy
    universeNode.ChildNodes.Add(solarSystemNode);
    solarSystemNode.ChildNodes.Add(planetNode);
    solarSystemNode.ChildNodes.Add(meteorNode);
    planetNode.ChildNodes.Add(moonNode);

    return universeNode;
}
```

When your serialize the object to JSON you would expect this in return

```
{
    Name: "Universe",
    ChildNodes: [
        {
            Name: "Solar System",
            ChildNodes: [
                {
                    Name: "Planet",
                    ChildNodes: [
                        {
                            Name: "Moon",
                            ChildNodes: []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    Name: "Meteor",
                    ChildNodes: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When you deserialize this JSON to JS object, you can simply access to your object graph easily just with traversing your `ChildNodes` property.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should process your object server side in order to have real tree nodes, i.e.

```
myObject
{
  string name;
  List<myObject> children;
}
```

If your serialization library knows how to send this to the client, displaying the data in a tree client side will be straightforward.

Comment: First build a map allowing constant time access to your nodes by name. Then begin by the node which has no parent and build its children list recursively using your node dictionary.